# Seeding with has_one relationship, Ruby on Rails (edited)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to seed data for my app. I managed to do this, but the code is ugly, and it possibly can be a lot easier. I;m a complete beginner so I would be grateful for any help. I had to create one profile and one todolist for each user, and 5 todoitems for each todolist.

```
 user1 = User.create!( username: "Fiorina", password_digest: "123456")
 profile1 = user1.create_profile(gender: "female", first_name: "Carly", last_name: "Fiorina", birth_year: 1954)
todolist1 = user1.todo_lists.create(list_name:"List1", list_due_date:Date.today + 1.year)
 user2 = User.create!( username: "Trump", password_digest: "123456")
 profile2 = user2.create_profile( gender: "male", first_name: "Donald", last_name: "Trump", birth_year: 1946)
 todolist2 = user2.todo_lists.create(list_name:"List2", list_due_date:Date.today + 1.year)
 user3 = User.create!( username: "Carson", password_digest: "123456")
 profile3 = user3.create_profile( gender: "male", first_name: "Ben", last_name: "Carson", birth_year: 1951)
 todolist3 = user3.todo_lists.create(list_name:"List3", list_due_date:Date.today + 1.year)
 user4 = User.create!( username: "Clinton", password_digest: "123456")
 profile4 = user4.create_profile( gender: "female", first_name: "Hillary", last_name: "Clinton", birth_year: 1947)
 todolist4 = user4.todo_lists.create(list_name:"List4", list_due_date:Date.today + 1.year)

 for i in 0..4 
 todolist1.todo_items.create(due_date: Date.today + 1.year, title: "TodoItem1", description: "Opis", completed: 1)
 end

 for i in 0..4 
 todolist2.todo_items.create(due_date: Date.today + 1.year, title: "TodoItem2", description: "Opis", completed: 1)
  end

  for i in 0..4 
 todolist3.todo_items.create(due_date: Date.today + 1.year, title: "TodoItem3", description: "Opis", completed: 1)
   end

   for i in 0..4 
 todolist4.todo_items.create(due_date: Date.today + 1.year, title: "TodoItem4", description: "Opis", completed: 1)
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DRY` it (don't repeat yourself):

```
[
  {last_name:'Fiorina', first_name:'Carly', gender:'female', birth_year:1954},
  {last_name:'Trump', first_name:'Donald', gender:'male', birth_year:1946},
  {last_name:'Carson', first_name:'Ben', gender:'male', birth_year:1951},
  {last_name:'Clinton', first_name:'Hillary', gender:'female', birth_year:1947},
].each_with_index do |p, index|
  user = User.create!( username: p[:last_name], password_digest: "123456")
  profile = user.create_profile(p) # note that p only has fields for profile attributes
  todolist = user.create_todo_list(list_name:"List#{index+1}", list_due_date:Date.today + 1.year)
  5.times.each{|i|
    todolist.create_todo_item(due_date: Date.today + 1.year, title: "TodoItem#{i+1}", description: "Opis", completed: 1)
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can  `build_profile` for has_one relation ship and used `todo_lists.build` for has_many try this way

```
User.create!( username: "Fiorina", password_digest: "123456").build_profile(gender: "female", first_name: "Carly", last_name: "Fiorina", birth_year: 1954).save!
```

for has_many relation ship

```
User.create!( username: "Fiorina", password_digest: "123456").todo_lists.build().save!
```

Comment: ok can you please put complete error and your model structure in question so that i can view you association and error

Comment: @user3748496 i have edited post accordingly and if you have again got error then. it will be great if you are put your complete error message

Comment: I tried all the options and I was  still getting an error. I got this to work - I'm very grateful for your help - but the code is ugly and I'm sure this can be done a lot easier. I edited first post to show you what I mean. After creating TodoList, I had to create 5 TodoItems for each TodoList.